# Buscar e Extrair uma linha ou palavras de um código fonte com Python 3

Tags: python

Eu preciso escrever um *script* que consiga extrair uma determinada linha em um código fonte com o Python, consegui ler o código fonte, mas não consigo filtrar, já li a documentação e fiquei meio perdido.

Até agora cheguei nesse resultado:

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MpUj-Aua48"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
keyword = f.search(r'<meta name="keywords"(.*)">')
```

Queria extrair as informações dentro da linha:

```html
<meta name="keywords" content="4k video test, 4k video demo, ultra tv video, video 4k for shop mode, ultra video tv demo play, 2160p video test, hd sourround video test, samsung tv demo, s...">
```

E capturar apenas as palavras chaves do código fonte.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) para fazer o *parsing* do HTML.

Basta instalar com:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Aí no seu código você pega o HTML como você já fez:

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MpUj-Aua48"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Agora o BeautifulSoup faz o trabalho mais complexo, que é ler o HTML e buscar as tags que você você precisa:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
meta_tag = soup.head.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'keywords'})
keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in meta_tag['content'].split(',')]
```

---

Explicando:

- Criar objeto BeautifulSoup

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  ```
- Procurar pela primeira tag `<meta>` dentro do `<head>` que tenha o atributo `name` e este contenha o valor `keywords`

  ```
  meta_tag = soup.head.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'keywords'})
  ```

  O método [soup.find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) retorna a primeira tag que for encontrada ou `None` caso nenhuma tag case com os filtros passados. No exemplo acima estou pedindo ao BeautifulSoup que me retorne um elemento cuja *tag* seja `<meta>` e que contenha o atributo `name` com o valor `keywords`. Se este elemento não existir no HTML passado, `meta_tag` recebera `None` como valor.
- Quebrar a string em uma lista com as *keywords* (eu uso o método [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) e [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para quebrar a string e remover os espaços excedentes)

  ```
  keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in meta_tag['content'].split(',')]
  ```

Resultado:

```
[
    "4k video test",
    "4k video demo",
    "ultra tv video",
    "video 4k for shop mode",
    "ultra video tv demo play",
    "2160p video test",
    "hd sourround video test",
    "samsung tv demo",
    "s...",
]
```

---

#### Exemplo completo:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MpUj-Aua48"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = f.read().decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
meta_tag = soup.head.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'keywords'})
keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in meta_tag['content'].split(',')]

print('=== Keywords ===')
for k in keywords:
    print(f' - {k}')
```

<sup>Código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-373053-6333)</sup>

Resultado:

```
=== Keywords ===
 - 4k video test
 - 4k video demo
 - ultra tv video
 - video 4k for shop mode
 - ultra video tv demo play
 - 2160p video test
 - hd sourround video test
 - samsung tv demo
 - s...
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de conseguir o que vc quer:

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MpUj-Aua48"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

alvo = None
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
   if '<meta name="keywords"' in str(line):
       alvo = line
       break

print('Alvo: ',alvo, sep='\n')
```

Saída:

```
b'      <meta name="keywords" content="4k video test, 4k video demo, ultra tv video, video4k for shop mode, ultra video tv demo play, 2160p video test, hd sourround video test, samsung tv demo, s...">\n'
```

Converta `alvo` para str e extraia o que precisar da forma q achar mais conveniente.

Usando o exemplo da sua tentativa:

```
import re
result = re.search(r'<meta name="keywords"(.*)">', str(l))
print(result.group(0))
```

Saída:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="4k video test, 4k video demo, ultra tv video, video 4k for shop mode, ultra video tv demo play, 2160p video test, hd sourround video test, samsung tv demo, s...">
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/urlib-request-readlines1)